# thread access between appdomains

Tags: .net

A thread created in a app domain can be moved to other appdomain. Since each appdomain is isolated from each other,

1. how does once can access the thread created in app domain in the
   other appdomain?
2. Any examples for this
3. How does the CLR keep track of this and handles the movement of threads?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a `Thread` object, then it cannot be 'moved' across an AppDomain boundary without serializing it. You can however interact with objects in different AppDomains via remoting.

Comment: as per the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a60kkx8k.aspx. : There is not a one-to-one correlation between application domains and threads. Several threads can be executing in a single application domain at any given time and a particular thread is not confined to a single application domain. That is, threads are free to cross application domain boundaries; a new thread is not created for each application domain

Comment: @Raghav55: `Thread` objects (as in, [`System.Threading.Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)) and threads are not the same thing.

Comment: @LukeH: It would be greatful an example is provided for this.

Answer (score 0):

> as per the msdn msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a60kkx8k.aspx. :
>   There is not a one-to-one correlation between application domains and
>   threads. Several threads can be executing in a single application
>   domain at any given time and a particular thread is not confined to a
>   single application domain. That is, threads are free to cross
>   application domain boundaries; a new thread is not created for each
>   application domain

From the same article :

> "At any given time, every thread is executing in an application
>   domain. Zero, one, or more than one thread might be executing in any
>   given application domain. The run time keeps track of which threads
>   are running in which application domains. You can locate the domain in
>   which a thread is executing at any time by calling the GetDomain
>   method.".

Important point is at anytime a given thread is only confined to one AppDomain. And this is important, in case if the thread aborts or throws unhandled exception, then its only the containing AppDomain that will be affected. What can be shared between threads is data(i.e. objects) derived from MarshalByRefObject or MarshalByValueObject classes.